# SQL запрос для получения объектов

Tags: android, sqlite

Есть таблицы

> 1) Objects -> objId | objName
>
> 2) ObjectGroup -> objId | groupId (у одного объекта может быть несколько групп)
>
> 3) Group-> groupId | groupName | isHidden  (группа может быть скрытой)

Нужно из таблицы Objects достать те объекты у которых все указанные в таблице ObjectGroup группы являются скрытыми в  Group.

Используется DBHelper и прямые sql запросы.
Не могу составить запрос..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Составил вот такой запрос (это кусочек), на первый взгляд, работает.
С базу вытягиваются все объекты у которых нет групп или если все указанные для них группы isHidden = 1 (скрыты)

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Objects    
    + " LEFT JOIN " + ObjectGroup + " ON " + ObjectGroup.objId + " = " + Objects.objId 
    + " AND " + ObjectGroup.groupId 
    + " in (SELECT " + Group.groupId + " FROM " + Group + " WHERE " + Group.isHidden +" = 0)"    
    + " WHERE " + ObjectGroup.objId + " IS NULL";
```

> Group.isHidden -> 1 скрыт, 0 не скрыт.